# How do I use the scalerel package for LaTeX

Tags: unicode, ctan

I need to use the [scalerel package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scalerel) available form CTAN. What do I need to do to use/install the package after I download and unzip the directory? I use TeXworks as my LaTeX editor on my Mac.

Comment: You should not install packages manually. I think nowadays every TeX distribution has a program to install packages.

Comment: if you use mac, you have probably either mactex or texlive. Open a terminal and type `tlmgr install scalerel` to install a package

Comment: All the warnings against manual installation are true.  Yet, in this case, until you install it officially, copying the sty file from CTAN to your working directory will get it up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT ALL costs avoid manual install
If a package is available use your TeX manager to install it in sync with all the hundreds of other packages so as to maintain the interdependent relationships such as font mapping.

[EDIT since I posted this answer Moewe has produced a nice generic answer for all packages see [How can I install a package on MikTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484084/how-can-i-install-a-package-on-miktex) ]

If your TeX is MiKTeX then run MiKTeX-console go to packages select scalerel ask the manager to download and install. It should then do all the other necessary rebuilding database tasks. However it should do no harm to run TASKS update filenames database etc.[image]

If your Tex is Tex Live run TLMgr --gui similarly locate scalerel ask the manager to download and install [image]

In this exceptionally simple case just unzip and keep all the files in the one folder DO NOT open scalerel.tex  use yourOWN.tex file to load the adjoining scalerel.sty but read the scalerel.pdf first.

If you can not find a package easily in the tex manager they both allow you to filter search on just a part word so either would have listed scalerel using e.g. `constrain`

If you must download manually from Ctan first look for a-well-built.tds.zip
anything else ask before download.

Comment: Thanks @KJO for your help