# MiKTeX: File 'memoir.cls' not found

Tags: errors, pdftex, pdf, miktex, viewers

With the code as below, I can not read PDF from my TeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}


\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=DarkBlue,
  linkcolor=DarkBlue,
  linktoc=page,
  urlcolor=black,
}

\title{Title}
\date{mardi, le 19 novembre 2019}
\author{Simon \textsc{Zugmeyer}}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\newcommand{\titlemath}[2]{\texorpdfstring{#1}{#2}} 
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{{\textbf{TODO:~}#1}}}

\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}[thrm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}[thrm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemm}[thrm]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}[thrm]{Definition}
\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rmrk}[thrm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}
\renewcommand\thehypo{\textit{\Alph{hypo}}}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\newcommand{\vphi}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\ol}{\overline}
\newcommand{\2}{{2^*}}
\newcommand{\p}{{p^*}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hess}{Hess}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ent}{Ent}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dive}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ic}{\mathbin{\Square}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\epi}{epi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lip}{Lip}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ric}{Ric}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\sbra}{[}{]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pare}{(}{)}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\;=\numexpr\mathcode`\;-\string"4000\relax}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\cleardoublepageeven{\clearpage\if@twoside
  \ifodd\c@page \thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}
  \newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\let\oldsbra\sbra
\def\sbra{\@ifstar{\oldsbra}{\oldsbra*}}
\let\oldpare\pare
\def\pare{\@ifstar{\oldpare}{\oldpare*}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\input{cover_jury}

\frontmatter

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
  \input{acknowledgements}
  \input{intro_fr}
\end{otherlanguage}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\input{intro}
\input{chap1}
\input{chap2}
\input{chap3}
\backmatter
\input{index}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{biblio_main}

\cleardoublepageeven
\input{back}

\end{document}
```

The problems appears on the screen like in the image below. How can I fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: It seems the compiler cannot find a file. Which one is unreadable on your screenshot. Do you really think its possible to help with these elements?

Comment: Go to the miktex console and try to install memoir there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You have a better crystal ball than me :o)

Comment: @Bernard this wasn't a crystal ball. I simply looked at the picture and see "memoir.cls not found"

Comment: I could only read ‘File not found’ (I have a comparatively small screen).

Comment: "Go to the miktex console and try to install memoir there" How? Could you tell me step by step!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484084/how-can-i-install-a-package-on-miktex for example.

Comment: https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console